How to check if repeated digits in a 4-digit index appear only in a row and no more than three times
The index consists of 4 digits, the digits can be repeated, but only in a row and no more than three times. That is, 3331 is correct, 1212 is incorrect. I need to add a check that the numbers are exactly in a row.
#include <QVector>
#include "examplevalidator.h"

ExampleValidator::ExampleValidator(QObject *parent)
    : QValidator(parent) { }

ExampleValidator::~ExampleValidator() { }

QValidator::State ExampleValidator::validate(QString &input, int &pos) const {
    QVector<int> chek(10, 0);
    int lenght = input.count();

    if (lenght > 4) {
        return QValidator::Invalid;
    }

    if (input.indexOf(QString("121"))) {
        return QValidator::Invalid;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < input.count(); i++) {
        QChar current = input.at(i);

        if (current < QChar('0') and current > QChar('9')) {
            return QValidator::Invalid;
        } else {
            int digit = current.digitValue();
            chek[digit]++;
            if (chek[digit] > 3) {
                return QValidator::Invalid;
            }
        }
    }

    if (lenght < 4) {
        return QValidator::Intermediate;
    }

    return QValidator::Acceptable;
}

I tried to add a substring check (if input.indexOf...), but nothing worked.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! First, please take the [tour] to get a better idea about what Stack Overflow is. You must then read [ask] to get an idea about how to ask questions here (the editing history should give you hints, such as proper code formatting and title formulation). The quality standards are strict here. Please take this into account so that you avoid having a negative experience here which could lead to a post ban.

About this question here: you haven't told us what's wrong with the attempt you shared. You said "I tried to add a substring check", but for what? You also said "but nothing worked", how so? How did you notice it did not work. You have to be specific and detailed.

A [mre] is essential, so that we can copy-paste it to test directly on our machines. I tried to make one from the code you shared (which is clear enough in my opinion, but you have to minimize the effort we have to make). Take a look at it, and consider editing your question to add it in, if it does reproduce your issue (I was messing with it to test, so I might have changed a few things there. Check for any changes). https://hastebin.com/share/rulovegige.cpp

The best approach for implementing these kinds of requirements might be to start with a pen and paper if the logic seems too complex to work out mentally. Sometimes visualizing the rules and working through examples manually can provide clarity before translating the logic into code.

Sorry for the long comments, but I think they might be helpful. One last piece of advice. Please add a short description about your current attempt. We can read the code, but it's better for us to understand your current train of thoughts before we suggest solutions.

You have almost 1 bug/line in validate, some of which look like you typed randomly (e.g. what is if (input.indexOf(QString("121"))) supposed to achieve?). As per How do I ask a good question, you should have spent some time researching your problem before asking. Like @A.R.M, I suggest you restart from scratch with a pen and paper. Clue to get you started: first test pos == 0, then input[pos - 1] compared to '0' and '9'. After that, you know a character was typed (pos > 0) and is a digit, so I leave the rest for you to complete.

//Maybe something like this?
/*
  The function tries to parse the
  string str as intended by the 
  topic author.
  The limit is the length of a 
  continuous sequence in a line.
  But this will not work with a 
  string like "1122" which contains 
  more than one sequence.
  This algorithm can be used in a 
  validator implementation.  
*/

bool foo(QString str, int limit)
{
    using type=QString::size_type;
    type first{-1}, last{-1};

    /*
      Looping through the string, 
      we remember the index of the 
      beginning and end (the first 
      one encountered) of a continuous 
      sequence of identical characters.          
      Then we check the presence of 
      a character from the found 
      sequence, before and after 
      its location in the line. 
    */

    for(type i=0; i<str.length()-1; i++){
        if(str.at(i)==str.at(i+1)){
            if(first== -1){
                first=i;
                --limit;
            }
            --limit;
            last=i+1;
        }else if(first!= -1){
            break;
        }
    }

    if(limit>=0 && first>=0 && last>0 && first!=last
        && !str.left(first).contains(str.at(first))
        && !str.last(str.size()-last-1).contains(str.at(first)))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}



qDebug()<<foo("1234", 2);   //false
qDebug()<<foo("3341", 2);   //true
qDebug()<<foo("133334", 2); //false
qDebug()<<foo("13343", 2);  //false
qDebug()<<foo("31334", 2);  //false
qDebug()<<foo("3341", 2);   //true
qDebug()<<foo("4133", 2);   //true
qDebug()<<foo("3333", 3);   //false

